# Tableau: Adding Red and Green arrows to a column

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 columns that I have in Tableau and one of them is date (Column A) and the other one is survey answer ( Satisfied, not satisfied, no comment). On the survey answer column I would like to indicate its growth over date (column A) using red or green arrow. Any thoughts on how I can to do that?

Comment: post some sample `data`,and required output format in `Tableau`

Comment: I think this may answer your question. http://www.bfongdata.com/2015/04/adding-colored-flag-arrows.html

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this post by Jonathan Drummey?

http://drawingwithnumbers.artisart.org/older-but-still-useful-conditional-formatting/